# saving webbrowser url to xml and retriving

Tags: c#, xml, webbrowser-control

I am trying to save my webbrowser controler URL to a xml file but I am getting an issue with certain characters preventing the save.

When I open a simple URL like this:

`www.saypeople.com`

It succesfully saves, however when I want to save webpage url like this:

`http://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?as_q=filetype:pdf +transistor+ AND&num=10&btnG=Search+Scholar&as_epq=&as_oq=unknown+unclear&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=+ &as_publication=+ &as_ylo=&as_yhi=&as_sdt=1.&as_sdtp=on&as_sdtf=&as_sdts=5&hl=en`

The save fails.

I have checked a lot things and have discovered that my code only does not save when the url contains any of the two characters `&<`.

Please help me out.

Here is my code...

```
    public static DialogResult Show(string Title,  String url)
    {
        MsgBox = new addfav();
        MsgBox.textBox1.Text = Title;
        MsgBox.textBox2.Text = url;
        MsgBox.ShowDialog();
        return result;


    }
    const string dataxml = "data.xml";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //textBox2.Text containing webpage url
       //textBox1.Text containing webpage title

        try
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(dataxml);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            XmlNode currNode;

            XmlDocumentFragment docFrag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
            docFrag.InnerXml = "<fav>" + "<Title>" + textBox1.Text + "</Title>" + "<url>"+  textBox2.Text + "</url>" + "</fav>";
            // insert the availability node into the document 
            currNode = doc.DocumentElement;
            currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild);
            //save the output to a file 
            doc.Save(dataxml);
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Added"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        } 


        MsgBox.Close();
    }
```

and
how can i retrive url by searching specific title in xml.

```
<fav>
<Title>hello</Title>
<url><![CDATA[http://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?as_q=filetype:pdf +hello+ AND&num=10&btnG=Search+Scholar&as_epq=&as_oq=unknown+unclear&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=+ &as_publication=+ &as_ylo=&as_yhi=&as_sdt=1.&as_sdtp=on&as_sdtf=&as_sdts=5&hl=en]]></url>
</fav>
<fav>
<Title>toad</Title>
<url><![CDATA[http://www.sciencedaily.com/search/?keyword=toad+ AND unknown OR unclear]]></url>
</fav>
```

i want to search and save the url of toad title in string... please help me out...
thx

Comment: Would be nice if you also posted the exception you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the URL in a CDATA section like:

```
<![CDATA[THE URL CONTENT]]>
```

Your problems result from the fact that you can not used & and < as XML-data, as they have special meanings in XML: & starts an XML entity, < starts an XML tag. So when you need to add & and < as values, it's easiest to used a CDATA section.

**EDIT**
You may try the following:

```
XmlDocumentFragment docFrag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
docFrag.InnerXml = "<fav>";
docFrag.InnerXml += String.Format("<Title>{0}</Title>", textBox1.Text);
docFrag.InnerXml += String.Format("<Url><![CDATA[{0}]]></Url>", textBox2.Text);
docFrag.InnerXml += "</fav>";
```

Comment: now i have another question .. i want to search a title in xml and store its url to string. question edited with detail... thx

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(url)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
docFrag.InnerXml = "<fav>" + "<Title>" + textBox1.Text + "</Title>"
                   + "<url>"+  textBox2.Text + "</url>" + "</fav>";
```

`<`, `>` and `&` that caused you problems are markup in XML. `InnerXML` does not escape markup and those characters get written as they are which would result in an invalid XML fragment. For adding the URL, use `InnerText` instead. It escapes those characters.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate through an XML file, you have to use a navigator as shown here.

```
XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument([location of the file]);
XPathNavigator Navigator = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();

String url_nav = "fav/url/text()";
XPathNodeIterator url_iterator = Navigator.Select(url_nav);

String URL_value = url_iterator.Current.Value;

url_iterator.MoveNext();
```

If the file is too heavily nested, go for XML serialization.